# Using ADODBAPI-Python

Tags: python, database

Can you list some resources that explain using ADODBAPI in python.?

Comment: should be community wiki

Comment: It may be helpful to know what versions of Python you are using.

Answer (score 1):

ADO can be accessed with [win32 extensions for python](http://python.net/crew/mhammond/win32/Downloads.html).

ADO is acessible through COM objects.

You can have a look at this page that would give a lot of info: http://www.ecp.cc/pyado.html

Answer (score 0):

If you are referring to the Python package, here is a quick reference guide:

http://adodbapi.sourceforge.net/quick_reference.pdf

This includes a link to

https://www.connectionstrings.com/

which will help you format the connection string for whatever database file type you are using.